# Querying Processed Transactions in Solana – Alternative Methods Needed

Tags: transactions, rpc, api

I am currently retrieving transaction information using the getTransactions method with the commitment levels 'finalized' or 'confirmed'. However, I need to access transaction information with a 'processed' commitment level. I understand that this is not possible with the getTransactions method. Is there an alternative way to achieve this?

The reason for this requirement is that when I subscribe to logsSubscribe via WebSocket with a 'processed' commitment, I receive the transaction ID. But when I query this transaction ID using getTransactions, I often get the following response:

**{"jsonrpc":"2.0","error":{"code":-32602,"message":"Method does not support commitment below 'confirmed'"},"id":1}.**

This is presumably because the transaction status is not yet confirmed or finalized.

Any guidance or alternative solutions would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Did you find a way how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

What’s the use case for getting a transaction which the results might be reverted or changed.

Are you building an application that can’t wait for another 5 to 10 seconds to confirm the transaction status and results?

I’ll start from trying subscribe to block updates using web socket.

And filter out the transactions that you care about.

Or another way will be deploying your own validator with modified core, can lets you query unconfirmed transactions.